# How to check Unicode of string data which is supposed to be inserted in PostgreSQL table using Python language?

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode

I want to insert data into a table in PostgreSQL, data is string or array of strings, the problem is that data contain some words (or string) which are not in utf8, and it makes the following error :

```
DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe2 0x80 0x20
```

the code that I am using is the following and it is in Python:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tst1 (tweet,words,tag,unknown_tags) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);", (row[1],words,tags[0],tags[1:]))
```

In order to prevent inserting data with inappropriate Unicode, I was wondering if there is a way in python (or in PostgreSQL) to check the Unicode of the data before insert it into tst1 table?

Comment: The better approach is to decode your input data from its encoding and pass to PostgreSQL as a Unicode object. If your input data is in a text file, you could try opening it with a number of decoders in a try/except tree or use the chardet module to autodetect the encoding.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack in fact the data is coming from another table in the database which contain some Chinese words in some tweets (I am just splitting tweets into arrays words and hashtags ), but it is not clear to me how to "decode your input data from its encoding and pass to PostgreSQL as Unicode" in my case? I already drop the db and restore it with correct Unicode (utf8) but it doesn't change anything and I still have these errors whit some string data in the dataset

Comment: I think @Daniel has answered your current question. Rather than change the scope, ask a new question and detail the root problem as described in your comment, then paste a link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use always unicode strings internally. You should decode your strings directly at the point of input, e.g.:

```
try:
    tags = tags.decode('utf8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # do what ever you like to do, if input is invalid
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but tags and keywords are arrays(list) so I face the error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
is there any other special method or I should use it in for loop?

Comment: @Farimah replace `tags = tags.decode('utf8')` with a for loop which executes `.decode()` on each string element